# Is it possible to define constants in CSS?

Tags: css

I use a few colors throughout my CSS style sheet. For example,

```
#testdiv{
  background: #123456;
}
```

Is it possible to define that color by name so I can reference it in the CSS sheet like the following?

```
#testdiv{
  background: COLORNAME;
}
```

Comment: If you use a framework such as SASS, you'll get this feature along with other brilliant features.

Comment: Yes, they're now called [CSS custom properties](https://mobile.htmlgoodies.com/html5/css/a-guide-to-using-css-variables.html)

Comment: if you are expecting something like this ```const myColor="#ffg433";```  just like any programming language would provide, but sadly it's not there, you better define a custom style and reuse it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is probably a better practice to define a CSS class and reuse it on each element you want to assign the color to rather than coding it to a specific element.

Like so:

```
.darkBackground {
   background: #123456;
}

.smallText {
   font-size: 8pt;
}
```

It also helps to know that an element can have multiple classes applied, so you can break out your "Constant" element values into separate classes and apply more than one as needed.

```
<div id="myDiv1" class="darkBackground smallText"></div>
<div id="myDiv2" class="darkBackground bigText"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not too fond of your example. I believe CSS classes are best used to classify the html document structure. A class called darkBackground doesn't describe the structure of the document, and creates a conceptual coupling of the document to some aspect of the appearance - which is exactly what CSS is supposed to bring us away from. If a future developer needs to switch to light backgrounds, they'll potentially have to edit loads of html to use class "lightBackground" or defy the meaning of their classes by editing the "darkBackground" rule to reference a light colour.

Comment: @csj Feel free to edit my answer with a better example if you like

Comment: Truth be told, your example does address the fundamental issue experienced by the op and others: css does not provide constants (the reasons for that are a whole different debate). Dealing with it seems to boil down to 3 options: 1. (your suggestion) use css classes to identify the style rather than the structure. 2. (probabilityzero's answer) use some form of server side programmatic css generator. 3. Give up, accept the nuisance, and embrace the css paradigm as is. Given that your answer was accepted uncontested and I have a preference for 2 or 3, I figured I'd add my 2 cents. Cheers

Comment: @csj, most of your comment here is an "answer", you could have just submitted it as one. I agree that JohnFx does not actually answer the question asked, so down-voting.

Comment: @Abacus. I didn't submit a separate answer because my own approaches were already represented by other answers. Rather, my goal in providing a comment was to offer a direct challenge to an answer that had been accepted as correct.

Comment: While I agree with "It is probably a better practice to define a CSS class and re-use it on each element you want to assign the color to ", a problem with this approach is where the colour is to be applied for different attributes - for example I have an SVG rect element that should be the same colour as the background for some li element, the svg rect requires fill:red while the li element requires background:red. Using this approach I would have to define the colour in two separate places.

Comment: @rom99 Have you tried SASS or LESS as suggested in a couple other answers? For anyone wanting a more powerful css that is alleviated of the issue you describe, these are both worth exploring.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually answer the question, and as others has stated, the advice is questionable.

Comment: Alright I have a question. Why is CSS (Cascading STYLE Sheets) recommended for structure only. As found on http://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/htmlcss#whatcss - "This is referred to as the separation of structure (or: content) from presentation." That's just my opinion, but to me that means that @JohnFx gave the proper answer. He is using CSS the way it was made to be used. Color is part of Style.

Comment: @DuhProgrammer13 You're correct that "Color is part of Style." The OP's and JohnFx's use of css to provide a background color is fine. My comment pertained to the class "darkBackground," named to reflect style rather than html structure, causing the html itself to indicate how it should look. If the class had been given a structural name (eg "codeBlock"), then the developer would remain unburdened should they wish to change codeBlock from having dark backgrounds to having light backgrounds. Of course, this quickly returns us to the OP's original question. I endorse probabilityzero's answer.

Comment: this is abjectly wrong. @A Hafid's answer is correct. if you were to present a hybrid it would be an improvement on both however.

Answer (score 106):

Yes, using classes is a good approach, but it is now possible to declare variables in CSS. And variables (especially color ones) are incredibly useful when you declare the same color (one where you need the hex value, if you use an integrated color it doesn't really matter as much).

And this is using plain CSS (and tbh, not nearly as elegant as using SASS or lessCSS) but it works for purposes of plain CSS. First off, define the actual variable in the `:root` block. You can define it in e.g. a `p` block as well (or anything else for that matter) but it'll only be available in that block. So to make sure it's globally accessible, put it in the root block:

```
:root {
  --custom-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

And using the `var` method (without the var method it won't be resolved as an actual reference) you can then reference it later:

```
p{
    color: var(--custom-color);
}
```

Since the `:root` block is (like all other CSS declarations) a fully functioning block that references elements, you can't declare something like:

```
:root{
    color: #00ff00;
}
```

That would reference the color attribute of every single element and set it to (in this example) `#00ff00`. Every variable name you declare has to start with `--`, meaning you can do:

```
:root{
    --color: #00ff00;
}
```

And again, if you can, use something like SASS or lessCSS. The ability to declare them by writing `@color = #fff`* and referencing with `@color`* is much easier than dealing with plain CSS and having to use the `var` keyword every time you want to access a custom property.

And you can access inline CSS with JS to get and/or alter the properties:

```
//Inline CSS
element.style.getPropertyValue("--custom-color");

// get variable from wherever
getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("--custom-color");

// set variable on inline style
element.style.setProperty("--custom-color", "#f0f0f0");
```

## NOTE!

This is a recently added feature, so [browser compatibility is important to check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*#Browser_compatibility). Especially firefox is worth paying extra attention to, as it has a gap between the introduction of the variable declarations themselves and the `var()` method. [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=var) currently estimates 91.65% of users run a browser with support for the method.

<sub>* with lessCSS it's `@color`, with SASS it is `$color`</sub>

Answer (score 83):

Not with plain CSS, but there are some CSS extensions that you could use, like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [less-css](http://lesscss.org/).

Here's an example of [Less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28stylesheet_language%29) CSS:

```
@color: #4D926F;

#header {
  color: @color;
}
h2 {
  color: @color;
}
```

Comment: It's unbelievable that constants haven't been added to CSS3 yet. Web development is in the middle ages.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka I felt that way for years, but after using less-css for a while and experiencing the multitude of features it brings to the table, I stopped caring about the deficits I perceived CSS as having.

Answer (score 24):

In CSS, you can declare your constant in *:root* block:

```
:root {
  --main-bg-color: #1596A7;
}
```

And using with the var() method:

```
.panel-header {
    background: var(--main-bg-color);
    color: ...
}
```

Answer (score 17):

There are a [couple of proposals](http://www.css3.info/summary-of-the-two-current-css-constants-proposals/) for this, so it might happen soon, but nothing has yet been standardised as far as I know.

The problem with using CSS classes for this is that they are no help if you want to use the same value for different properties, for example if you want to use a particular color value for a border on one element, and a background-color on another.

Comment: IMO, this should be the answer marked correct. Further, you cannot make a CSS class like `customers-process-step-color-1` and apply it automatically to pseudo elements like `:before`. You have to set the color to `:before` directly.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [Less](http://lesscss.org/).

Nowadays, using preprocessors like the above is a common practice for a better front-end development workflow.

It helps you being more organized and features like variables or mixins are some of the reasons they are worth taking into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Sass](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/controlling-color-with-sass-color-functions) variables:

```
$color: #4D926F;

.someclass{
  color: $color;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You can have constants in a `CSS` file, declaring them like this:

```
*{
 -my-lightBlue: #99ccff;
 -my-lightGray: #e6e6e6;
}
```

Then you can use them in the CSS file like this:

```
.menu-item:focused {
  -fx-background-color: -my-lightBlue;
}
```

After that you can use them programmatically like this:

```
progressBar.setStyle("-fx-accent: -my-lightBlue;");
```

Comment: That only applies to JavaFX css

Answer (score -7):

The standard way to do this is PHP. Add #define statements at the beginning of your CSS file, like

`#define COLORNAME: #123456;`

Instead of linking to the CSS file in the head of your HTML file, run a PHP script at that location. The script loads the CSS file, replaces all occurrences of `COLORNAME` by `#123456` and streams the patched text to the client using `echo` or `print`.

Alternatively, you could upload the source file (also using PHP), use PHP to create a CSS file once where all occurrences of #defines are replaced, and use that file in your HTML. This is more efficient, since you're doing the conversion only once, at the upload, instead of every time you load the HTML file.