# Is it possible to define a variable in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm learning CSS and HTML, and I'm doing a simple code example. In my CSS I use for many styles a color, to set a border color, or a text color!

Can I define this color to a Generic name? I ask this, because I think that if I want to change it later it's much easier change 1 line!

Example:

```
DEFINE MYCOLOR #000000

h1{text-color:MYCOLOR;}
#mydiv{background-color:MYCOLOR;}
```

I found this article([Is it possible to define constants in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847850/possible-to-define-a-constant-in-css)), BUT IT DIDN'T WORK FOR ME (so it's not duplicated), because 1 answer said to use class's, and it didn't work because I use MYCOLOR with different properties, and the other answers say to use a CSS extension.

Is it possible to do this with pure CSS and HTML?

(It's my first post, so sorry if it is a little confusing...)

Comment: "It's possible to do it with pure CSS and HTML?" Nope.

Comment: You're a C developer, aren't you? ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need a SCSS Pre-Processor to use variables (or — using the term loosely — constants) in writing your stylesheets.

The two major players in the Pre-Processor area are:

- [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) (my personal favorite, especially when used with [compass](http://compass-style.org/))
- [Less](http://lesscss.org/)

Some examples:

**SASS** (using scss syntax):

```
$mycolor: #000000;

h1 { color: $mycolor; }
```

**LESS**

```
@mycolor: #0000000;

h1 { color: @mycolor; }
```

To start out, my suggestion would be to play around with both in a [Codepen](http://codepen.io) or [CSSDeck](http://cssdeck.com/)  (which both offer SASS/LESS live compiling ) to get a feel for the syntax.

Pre Processors also provide you with more programatic things like mixins and control structures. Warning: Once you've started pre-processing, it is difficult to go back : )

Answer (score 5):

No, plain CSS doesn't give you a feature like this.

You'll need to use something like [Less](http://lesscss.org/) if you need that feature.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the short answer is yes, but not now (and possibly not for a while)

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/css-variables/ explains how to use the method that has been implemented for testing in the newest versions of Chrome.

The idea is to use code like:

```
:root {
    var-color: rgba(255,0,0);
}

h1 {
    color: var(color);
}
```

In reality though, the code for this has been removed from Webkit, and many people have commented that they don't really like it.

Hence, people often use SASS or LESS.

I've also written about that:

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/why-sass/

SASS makes that as easy as:

```
$brand-color: rgb(255,0,0);

h1 {
    color: $brand-color;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a preprocessor to accomplish your question and you have more than one choice. As mentioned in other answers you can use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

If you need help determining which one is right for you consider reading this [post by Chris Coyier.](http://css-tricks.com/sass-vs-less/0)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
.mycolorText{
    color: #000000;
}
.mycolorBg{
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Then in your html you do this:

```
<h1 class="mycolorText">
<div class="mycolorBg">
```

The trick with css and defining things like this is that you can combine classes on your elements.

Which means you can do this:

```
<div class="mycolorBg mycolorText">
```

While this doesn't let you do it in one place, it does let you do it in just 2 places which is still pretty simple to update.

Otherwise you would have to do what others say and use a css-preprocessor.