# How to declare variable in CSS

Tags: css, variables

Is it possible to declare your self a variable in CSS, for example if i had the same property for the following two tags

```
.cellLeft{
width: 45%;
min-height: 130px;

}
.cellRight{
width: 45%;
min-height: 130px;
}
```

Is it possible to declare x=130px
so i dont have to keep changing min-height everywhere 
like for example;

```
x=130px;
.cellLeft{
width: 45%;
min-height: x;

}
.cellRight{
width: 45%;
min-height: x;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [possible to define a constant in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847850/possible-to-define-a-constant-in-css)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a CSS preprocessor for this, like LESS or SASS. You can't do it with pure css. Have a look here: http://lesscss.org/ or here: http://sass-lang.com/ (I use LESS myself)

*Extra:*

A CSS-only solution to your example would be to use a modular approach in which you define multiple classes for specific attributes which you can re-use in your HTML. I would suggest doing this even when using a CSS preprocessor. So for your example you could make these classes:

```
.cell {
    width: 45%;
    min-height: 130px;
}
.cell-left {
}
.cell-right {
}
```

And then add both the cell and the cell-left / cell-right classes to your HTML elements. This way you only have to declare the width and min-height properties once.

Or, you could do:

```
.cell-left, .cell-right {
    width: 45%;
    min-height: 130px;
}
```

So you only have to change it once as well.

Comment: thanks alot Leon. that worked perfectly for my example!